# How to put/overlay values from 2 Venn diagram in R

Tags: r, overlay, venn-diagram

I am trying to show 2 values on Venn diagram in R.

Let's say we have a list of X and Y:

```
X = list(cond1 = c(...), cond2 = c(...), cond3 = c(...), cond4 = c(...))

Y = list(cond1 = c(...), cond2 = c(...), cond3 = c(...), cond4 = c(...))
```

cond1 in X and Y may have different values, sets; for instance:

```
X$cond1 = c(1,2,3,4,5)
Y$cond2 = c(1,4,5,6,7)
```

same applies to cond2, cond3 and cond4.

one can use different functions in R to draw Venn diagram separately for X and Y.

for instance using ggvenn library;

```
ggvenn(X) # venn1
ggvenn(Y) # venn2
```

how can we put values in Venn1 and Venn2 on the same Venn diagram?

**Edit:**

here is an example.

```
set.seed(123)
genes = paste0("gene", seq(1,1000))

X = list(
    cond1 = sample(genes, 200),
    cond2 = sample(genes, 100),
    cond3 = sample(genes, 120),
    cond4 = sample(genes, 60)   
)


Y = list(
    cond1 = sample(genes, 150),
    cond2 = sample(genes, 110),
    cond3 = sample(genes, 220),
    cond4 = sample(genes, 80)   
)

ggvenn(X, show_percentage = F)
ggvenn(Y, show_percentage = F)
```

X (up-left), Y(up-right). I want to have both values on the same Venn (bottom Venn diagram). I manually added values and color coded red for Y values.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for an extended Venn diagram?  Have you seen this? https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/venn-diagram-with-r-or-rstudio-a-million-ways/

Comment: Please make the question reproducible: add the output of `dput(X)` and `dput(Y)` to the questions, or a sample set of data.

Comment: I am familiar with the codes here: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/venn-diagram-with-r-or-rstudio-a-million-ways/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to do it with the `ggvenn` package as it currently stands.  You have to rewrite parts of the `ggvenn` code and call a certain function twice.

Here is how I did it.

1. Go to here: [ggvenn.R code](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggvenn/src/R/ggvenn.R).  Copy/paste **all** of these functions into your R session. This puts all of the packages functions in the global environment where R can see it.  There may be a more elegant way to do this, but this is the easiest but most messy way.
2. Now we will modify the `ggvenn` function so that it does what you want.  We will call it `my.ggvenn`.

```
### Anything with a ".plus" is something that I added to the base function
### data.plus is the "Y" in your example, and data is the usual "X".
my.ggvenn <- function(data, data.plus, columns = NULL,
                   show_elements = FALSE,
                   show_percentage = TRUE,
                   digits = 1,
                   fill_color = c("blue", "yellow", "green", "red"),
                   fill_alpha = .5,
                   stroke_color = "black",
                   stroke_alpha = 1,
                   stroke_size = 1,
                   stroke_linetype = "solid",
                   set_name_color = "black",
                   set_name_size = 6,
                   text_color = "black",
###This is the color of the Y numbers underneath
                   text_color.plus = "blue",
                   text_size = 4,
###This is the vertical justification
                   vjust.plus = 1,
                   label_sep = ",",
                   count_column = NULL,
                   show_outside = c("auto", "none", "always"),
                   auto_scale = FALSE)
{
  show_outside <- match.arg(show_outside)

### we run this function 2 times, one for X (data) and one for Y (data.plus).  
### The objective is to perform the identical diagrams but adjust the Y one lower with vjust.

  venn <- prepare_venn_data(data, columns, show_elements, show_percentage, digits,
                            label_sep, count_column, show_outside, auto_scale)

### this was added by me; you can check out what it does but it creates the formatting

  venn.plus <- prepare_venn_data(data.plus, columns, show_elements, show_percentage, digits,
                            label_sep, count_column, show_outside, auto_scale)
  
  g <- venn$shapes %>%
    mutate(group = LETTERS[group]) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(aes(x = x, y = y, group = group, fill = group),
                 alpha = fill_alpha) +
    geom_polygon(aes(x = x, y = y, group = group),
                 fill = NA,
                 color = stroke_color,
                 size = stroke_size,
                 alpha = stroke_alpha,
                 linetype = stroke_linetype)
  if (nrow(venn$labels) > 0) {
    g <- g +
      geom_text(data = venn$labels,
                aes(x = x, y = y, label = text, hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust),
                color = set_name_color,
                size = set_name_size)
  }
  if (nrow(venn$texts) > 0) {
    g <- g +
      geom_text(data = venn$texts,
                aes(x = x, y = y, label = text, hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust),
                color = text_color,
                size = text_size)
  }
### this adjusts all of the Y values down by vjust + vjust.plus and colors them.
  if (nrow(venn.plus$texts) > 0) {
    g <- g +
      geom_text(data = venn.plus$texts,
                aes(x = x, y = y, label = text, hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust+vjust.plus),
                color = text_color.plus,
                size = text_size)
  }
  if (nrow(venn$segs) > 0) {
    g <- g +
      geom_segment(data = venn$segs,
                   aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend),
                   color = text_color,
                   size = 0.5)
  }
  g <- g +
    scale_fill_manual(values = fill_color) +
    guides(fill = "none") +
    coord_fixed() +
    theme_void()
  return(g)
}
  
my.ggvenn(X,Y, show_percentage = F)
```

[image]